# DynamicList - Multiple columns

Tags: php

First of all I am not very familiar with this.

```
 $dynamicListBody = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category='Body' ORDER BY id ASC");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
             $id = $row["id"];
         $product_name = $row["product_name"];
         $details = $row["details"];
         $price = $row["price"];
         $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
         $dynamicListBody .= '
         <table width="95%">
              <tr>
               <td width="10%">
        <img style="border:#666 1px solid;" src="../stock_photos/' . $id . '.png" alt="' . $product_name . '" />
           </td>
               <td width="35%">
            <span class=itmttl>' . $product_name . '</span>
        <br />
                <span class=text>' . $details . '
                <br />
                €' . $price . '</span>
        <br />
                <form id="bd_itm1" name="bd_itm1" method="post" action="help_scripts/cart_functions.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
                <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add to Cart" />
                </form>
           </td>
           <td width="5%">
           </td>
           <td width="10%">
           </td>
           <td width="35%">
        <br />
        <form id="bd_itm2" name="bd_itm2" method="post" action="help_scripts/cart_functions.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
                <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add to Cart" />
                </form>
           </td>
              </tr>
             </table>';
    }
} else {
    $dynamicListBody = "We have no products listed in our store yet";
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

This displays my results in the first column  only. How can I display results in the second column as well
like
1 - a | 2 - b
3 - c | ...
without changing the above table layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x2    
<?php 
     $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category='Body' ORDER BY id ASC");
     $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
     if ($productCount > 0) {
        $i=0;
        $dynamicListBody = '<table width="95%">';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            $id = $row["id"];
            $product_name = $row["product_name"];
            $details = $row["details"];
            $price = $row["price"];
            $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
            $dynamicListBody .= ($i==0) ? '<tr>':''; 
            $dynamicListBody .= '
                <td width="10%">
                      <img style="border:#666 1px solid;" src="../stock_photos/' . $id . '.png" alt="' . $product_name . '" />
                </td>

                <td width="35%">
                  <span class=itmttl>' . $product_name . '</span>
                  <br />
                  <span class=text>' . $details . '<br />&euro;' . $price . '</span>
                   <br />
                    <form id="bd_itm1" name="bd_itm1" method="post" action="help_scripts/cart_functions.php">
                    <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="'.$id.'" />
                    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add to Cart" />
                    </form>
                </td>';
            $dynamicListBody .= ($i==1) ? '</tr>':''; 
            $i++;
            ($i==2) ? $i=0:'';
        } 
        $dynamicListBody.='</table>';
     } else {
        $dynamicListBody = "We have no products listed in our store yet";
     }
     mysql_close();
    ?>
//4

    <?php 
     $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category='Body' ORDER BY id ASC");
     $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
     if ($productCount > 0) {
        //iteration set to 0
        $i=0;
        $dynamicListBody = '<table width="95%">';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            $id = $row["id"];
            $product_name = $row["product_name"];
            $details = $row["details"];
            $price = $row["price"];
            $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
            //$i controls the first <tr> in the loop
            $dynamicListBody .= ($i==0) ? '<tr>':''; 
            $dynamicListBody .= '
                <td width="10%">
                      <img style="border:#666 1px solid;" src="../stock_photos/' . $id . '.png" alt="' . $product_name . '" />
                </td>

                <td width="35%">
                  <span class=itmttl>' . $product_name . '</span>
                  <br />
                  <span class=text>' . $details . '<br />&euro;' . $price . '</span>
                   <br />
                    <form id="bd_itm1" name="bd_itm1" method="post" action="help_scripts/cart_functions.php">
                    <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="'.$id.'" />
                    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add to Cart" />
                    </form>
                </td>';
            //is 3 as first iteration is 0 meaning 4 rows will get outputted when $i is 3 as started on 0 not 1
            $dynamicListBody .= ($i==3) ? '</tr>':''; 
            $i++;
            //note $i was set to 4(above $i++) before checking, meaning 4 rows have been outputted
            ($i==4) ? $i=0:'';
        } 
        $dynamicListBody.='</table>';
     } else {
        $dynamicListBody = "We have no products listed in our store yet";
     }
     mysql_close();
    ?>
```

Comment: I tried second solution first... It seems to work Perfectly... I am saying that because I cannot vote up. (1st one I didn't tried since the second one seems to work.) Thyank you

Comment: np, i see you wanted 2 across and what ever down, note that you need to have an even number of results returned or the last ending `</tr>` wont show n it may break the look, Hamids answer has errors with the `<?php` in the html block and the `€` should be `&euro;` :)

Comment: Hello, I want to understand a little bit what exactly we are saying to the code to enter things in the 2 columns... As I understood the everything happens here:`code'<br />$dynamicListBody .= ($i==1) ? '</tr>':'';<br />$i++;<br />($i==2) ? $i=0:'';`/code` But what exactly are we telling it to do? What if I want to display 3, 4, 5... columns.<br />Thank you

Comment: when im not working with oop, i would usually write a function block for tables like products($dbResult,$cols) then with the value of $cols-1 on the closing `</tr>`... the 2 in the example would be the value of $cols

Comment: I don't know why I am confused but is your solution that I used..!!! not the other one. Now as for the explanation... I hope you don't get unry on me...:) I am a bit confused here also... as i want only 4 columns why this($i==2) ? $i=0:''; isn't changing to ($i==4) ? $i=0:'';??? and why do I change the increment to 3 and not leaving it as is ==1???

Comment: np so you want 4 across? ok it looks like you want 2 across looking at `1 - a | 2 - b` with `3 - c | ...` and the table width="35%. ill add changes to the answer in 2 secs

Comment: no..... I don't want.... 2 is my plan... :) I think last night I missundestood the "increment" by 1 and 3.. You ment that it adds 3 more rows/values to the one we already have. (My thought was that we always add +1 value and then we break at 2nd or 5th as you said). The break at 5 and not 4 I didn't understand but as I see you changed it at your post :).

Comment: hmmm Hello, I am back for this, since I forgot a thing... The above code although is working perfect... is not as I needed it... Since it's rendering the row inside the table, when I add 20 items I have to wait until the whole table loads and then show. What should I change in order to render a table with the 2 td so if I have 6 items it will create 3 tables of 2. Thank you

Comment: @Lawrence for what I posted above should I just remove my 2 table lines [$dynamicListBody = '<table width="95%">';]  and just leave the rows to render or is a bad idea????

Comment: @Lawrence here is my new question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208246/dynamiclist-with-multiple-columns)

Comment: @Lawrence did you remove the post to the other question? thank you

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean this and i hope it'll be usefull for u

```
<?php

 $dynamicListBody = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category='Body' ORDER BY id ASC");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
    $i=0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
             $id = $row["id"];
         $product_name = $row["product_name"];
         $details = $row["details"];
         $price = $row["price"];
         $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
         $dynamicListBody .= '
         <table width="95%">';

         // to Display 4 cell and n row

          if( $i%4==0 )$dynamicListBody .= ' <tr> ';

         $dynamicListBody .= '    
               <td width="10%">
        <img style="border:#666 1px solid;" src="../stock_photos/' . $id . '.png" alt="' . $product_name . '" />
           </td>
               <td width="35%">
            <span class=itmttl>' . $product_name . '</span>
        <br />
                <span class=text>' . $details . '
                <br />
                €' . $price . '</span>
        <br />
                <form id="bd_itm1" name="bd_itm1" method="post" action="help_scripts/cart_functions.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
                <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add to Cart" />
                </form>
           </td>
           <td width="5%">
           </td>
           <td width="10%">
           </td>
           <td width="35%">
        <br />
        <form id="bd_itm2" name="bd_itm2" method="post" action="help_scripts/cart_functions.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
                <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add to Cart" />
                </form>
           </td>';

       if( $i%4==0 )$dynamicListBody .= ' </tr> ';
      $dynamicListBody .= ' 
             </table>';
             $i++;
    }
} else {
    $dynamicListBody = "We have no products listed in our store yet";
}
mysql_close();
?>
```